# Desindexar URLs de Versión Anterior

Tags: seo

Acabamos de mudarnos desde Joomla 2.5 a 3.8, y acabo de encontrar cerca de 1,5k URLs que vienen de la versión anterior y que estan indexadas-duplicadas entre si. He intentando desindexarlas con el WebMaster Tool pero estoy viendo que es una solución temporal.

> http://www.eexcellence.es/index.php?option=com_mailto&tmpl=component&template=sj_financial&link=dae19a2230fed32b98dd906a4525d5e1f4d50a87

También he intentado este comando en el HTACCESS pero no funciona, probablemente porque las URLs no estan en el BACKEND actual o no se muy bien porque.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} "option=com_mailto&tmpl=component&template=sj_financial" 
RewriteRule . http://www.eexcellence.es/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Que creéis que podría hacer?, gracias por vuestra ayuda

AGA

We have recently moved from Joomla 2.5 to 3.8, and I had just found aroun 1,5k URLs form the previouis one that are indexed and also duplicated. I have tried to desindexed with the Webmaster tools. But is a temporary solution.

> http://www.eexcellence.es/index.php?option=com_mailto&tmpl=component&template=sj_financial&link=dae19a2230fed32b98dd906a4525d5e1f4d50a87

I have tried as weel with the command but is not working

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} "option=com_mailto&tmpl=component&template=sj_financial" 
RewriteRule . http://www.eexcellence.es/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Thanks Alo Malbarez, for the next ones how I should placed the URLs in my questions?

Comment: Piensa que las urls antiguas de joomla pueden tener adquiridas cierta autoridad SEO.... lo ideal sería redirigir las antiguas urls a sus correspondientes nuevas para no perder posicionamiento, esto lo puedes hacer con el htaccess.
Te recomiendo utilices esta web para comprobar que la expresión regular que utilizas tiene la sintaxis correcta... [https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/)